# Difference between memset and initialization (array)?

Tags: c

I've been working with some C code and I would like to know what the difference is between next codes:

```
double myArray[5] = {0,0,0,0,0};
```

and

```
double myArray[5];
memset(myArray,0,5*sizeof(double));
```

Could there be a problem for replacing the second one with the first one? If so, what kind of problems might be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `memset` this way makes assumptions regarding the representation of floating point numbers, specifically that the representation of all bits 0 corresponds to the value 0.

If your system uses IEEE754 floating point representation (as are most systems you're likely to come across) this assumption holds.  However, if you find yourself running your code on some exotic system that does not, then you might not get the result you expect.

Comment: Incidentally, there was some regret in the IEEE-754 committee that a `memset` to −1 (255) would not fill an array with signaling NaNs. It is so close and just would have required specifying the sense of a signaling/quiet bit in the original standard.

Comment: This is the best site I've ever visited.

Comment: Thank you very much. Could you add to your answer what kind of problems might be? I'd help a lot if you could give an example or a case.

Comment: @Carlos I've heard of systems where a NULL pointer is not all bytes 0, though I've never personally came across such a system.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to [dbush's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68537749/), although there likely wouldn't be a problem on most modern systems using `memset`, the `memset` version (as written) is more brittle.  If someday you decided to change the size of `myArray`, then one of two things would happen with the version using the braced initializer list:

- If you decreased the size of `myArray`, you will get a compilation error about having too many initializers.
- If you increased the size of `myArray`, any elements without an explicit initializer will automatically be initialized to 0.

In contrast, with the `memset` version:

- If you decreased the size of `myArray` without remembering to make a corresponding change to `memset`, `memset` will write beyond the bounds of the array, which is undefined behavior.
- If you increased the size of `myArray` without remembering to make a corresponding change to `memset`, elements at the end will be uninitialized garbage.

(A better way to use `memset` would be to do `memset(myArray, 0, sizeof myArray)`.)

Finally, IMO using `memset` in the first place is more error-prone since it's quite easy to mix up the order of the arguments.